# What is the right way for working with Azure AD when supporting multiple environments?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am a Solution Architect responsible for setting up a project's infrastructure on Azure. The project should be running **in multiple environments** (dev, staging, prod). As far as I learned the best practice regarding environment separation in Azure is to use Resource Groups. That's what I did.

However, this is where things start getting tricky. Our application will use **Azure AD as OAuth Authorization Server**. I want to have my **AD isolated**, like everything else in my infrastructure. I don't want to accidentally modify a production user from the dev environment and for the dev environment, I want to be able to create a ton of test users which I don't want to see in production. So, isolation.

The problem is I don't see any option on how to do this. My first instinct was to create multiple ADs. But when I do that, they actually need to create a completely new tenant for each of these environments. This seems really messy to me. Have to support as many (almost empty) tenants as I want to have environments.

**Please, what is the right way how to do this?
Does Azure AD have some kind of support for isolation I require?
Am I missing something?**

*Note: this question was also asked in [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/614469/what-is-the-right-way-for-working-with-azure-ad-wh.html).*

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that a tenant is equivalent to a directory and a user is either in the directory or it's not. However, using RBAC, you can restrict the permissions on users so that they can't access particular services.  It would be good if you separated permissions by subscription which is what a lot of major companies do and that's how they know which workload a subscription handles.

Comment: Thank you for your response Matt. Sorry to get back to you took me so long. If I may, I have a follow-up question. Is it in any way possible to separate permissions for the management of the AD itself? There is a need from corporate to have management of the AD-part of the environments (users, groups, app registrations,...) separate per environment. Therefore having one group of users only being able to manage DEV, another only PROD, etc.

Comment: Yes - you can restrict contribution to each environment to different groups.  Global Admin will always have complete control over all environments, but you shouldn't be using global admin in this situation unless you are managing the top-level groups.  

Create user groups that have access only to particular resource groups and subscriptions.  This is your division of management.